# Beautiful soup - error pulling a website link that isn't on every looped page

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

I am working on my first web scrape and, thanks to the help of stackoverflow I have managed to put the following code together. This code works well to click through each of the pages and then go into each of the links to pull the info I need. However, it gets stuck at one of these links as there is no web info to pull.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

binary = FirefoxBinary('geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php')

url = 'http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php'
text = requests.get(url).text
page1 = BeautifulSoup(text, "html.parser")

def get_data(url, tries=0, max_tries=3):
    text_test2 = requests.get(url).text
    page2 = BeautifulSoup(text_test2, "html.parser")

    try:
        title = page2.find('h1', attrs={'class':'hl_2'}).text    
        content = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'cont'}).text
        phone = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_phone'}).text
        email_div = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_email'})
        email = email_div.find('a', attrs={'class': 'xsecondarylink'})['href']

    web_div = page2.find('div', attrs={'class':'sico ico_link'})
    web = web_div.find('a', attrs={'class':'xsecondarylink'})
    if web != None:
        web = web['href']

    except:
        if tries < max_tries:
            tries += 1
            print("try {}".format(tries))
            return get_data(url, tries)


    data = {'Name': [title],
            'Street address': [content], 
            'Phone number': [phone],
            'Email': [email],
            'Web': [web]            
            }

    return pd.DataFrame(data=data)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,80):
    print(i)
    page1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


    for div in page1.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'item'}):

        for a in div.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'initial_noline'}):
            if 'kid=' not in a['href'] : continue
            print('http://www.interzum.com' + a['href'])

            data = get_data('http://www.interzum.com' + a['href'])
            df = pd.concat([df, data])

    next_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('slick-next')
    next_button.click()
    time.sleep(20)

df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

I have tried numerous different ways to try and say, if the web doesn't exist then continue looping, if it does then pull me the href. But i keep getting an error message that 
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'web' referenced before assignment

I can't seem to put this together correctly with the info out there on the web. Any insights into what I am doing incorrectly would be really appreciated!

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to switch to selenium for retrieving info from specific pages as the content is not loaded always for requests. You can use the following as a framework.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
baseLink = 'http://www.interzum.com'
varLink = 'http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php?fw_goto=aussteller/blaettern&fw_ajax=1&paginatevalues=%7B%22stichwort%22%3A%22%22%7D&start={}&dat=231518http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php'
startUrl = 'http://www.interzum.com/exhibitors-and-products/exhibitor-index/exhibitor-index-15.php'
resultsPerPage = 20
i = 0
headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
results = []
final = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(startUrl, headers = headers)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    numPages = int(soup.select('a[rel=next]')[-2].text)
    links = list((baseLink + link['href'] for link in soup.select('[href*="fw_goto=aussteller/details&&kid="]')))
    results.append(links)
    for j in range(1, numPages):
        i+=20
        url = varLink.format(i)
        r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        links = list((baseLink + link['href'] for link in soup.select('[href*="fw_goto=aussteller/details&&kid="]')))
        results.append(links)

    totalList = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]

    for link in totalList:
        driver.get(link)
        try:
            title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1.hl_2').text    
            content = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.cont').text
            phone = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.sico.ico_phone').text
            email = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.sico.ico_email a.xsecondarylink').get_attribute('href')
            web = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.sico.ico_link a.xsecondarylink').get_attribute('href')
            final.append([title, content, phone, email, web])
        except Exception as e:
            print(link)
            print(e)
            continue
```